# Format Excel static variables

Tags: excel

So i have an app that gets Data from an Excel. In a sheet i have columns that have big text and my goal is to add breakpoints and apply text decorations like bold to some part of the text.

In excel i can do:
[image: Excel example]

When i get the Data from excel throw my api the text that it comes from the excel above will be just:

```
Example of a big big text. This is underlined I add a breakpoint but it doesnt recognize when i get the data
```

So even if i try to add like 
   this is recognized like text

Is there any way to get text from Excel formatted like in Excel?

Comment: ... and Excel breakpoint? What is that?

Comment: breakpoint / paragraph / breakline whatever you wanna call it

Comment: Iguess it depends on how you access the data and what langage are you using, not Excel itself.

Comment: Assuming you are using excel interop then perhaps look at the [Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.characters) of the Range.